# filepicker.io - on .pick / pickAndStore use generated thumbnail

Tags: filepicker.io

When the file picker is opened either using `.pick` or `.pickAndStore`, and an image is selected, a thumbnail of the original image is shown on the side.

I want to reuse that thumbnail, preferably from the already locally stored version. How can I access it e.g., with the filepicker API or other javascript library?

Comment: The thumbnail url isn't returned to the developer. The reason is that those thumbnails are temporarily generated either by Filepicker or the underlying service. Send an email to support@filepicker.io with more information about what you're trying to do and we'll probably open a feature request for it.

Answer (score 1):

The thumbnail you see during uploading is generated by FilePicker javascript as a data URI (eg, src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...") it never really exists.

Once the file is uploaded you can use the image conversion rest API:
https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#inkblob-images